# How to replace all nonnumeric values?

Tags: sql, teradata

**This is TERADATA** (not SQL Server, not Oracle )

I have a column of phone numbers:

```
(312)9879878
(298)989-9878
430-394-2934
394s9048ds987
..........
```

I need to clean this column into

```
3129879878
2989899878
4303942934
3949048987
..........
```

So that only numbers should stay. All other letters, special characters, hyphens ... should be removed. How can I do this?

Comment: Can you edit your question and share the table definition for your example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Which release of TD is running at your site?
If it's 14 or you got the oTranslate UDF installed you can simply do an old trick nesting Translate:

```
oTranslate(phonenum, oTranslate(phonenum, '0123456789', ''), '')
```

Comment: I have 14.01 So how would my query look like: `Select oTranslate(phonenum, oTranslate(phonenum, '0123456789', ''), '') FROM ...`

Comment: Yes, exactly. Simply try it

Comment: I got an error: `data type phonenum does not match a defined type name`

Comment: This error usually indicates that there's no function with this name. What is returned by: SELECT * FROM dbc.FunctionsV WHERE FunctionName LIKE '%TRANSLATE%'

Comment: I get 0 rows returned. You are right : there is no such function

Comment: Which release is returned by SELECT * FROM dbc.DbcInfoV; ? If it's actually a TD14 you should ask your DBA to run a DIP-script: DIPSYSFNC

Comment: I ran the query and got :                                          `RELEASE 13.10.06.06
VERSION 13.10.06.09a
LANGUAGE SUPPORT MODE Standard`

Comment: It's 13.10, not 14, maybe your client is 14. You might ask your DBA to install at least some of the Oracle functions like oTranslate and oReplace, they're really usefull.

Answer (score 1):

**Answer :**

> DECLARE @Input varchar(1000)
>
> SET @Input = '01 vishal 98-)6543'
>
> DECLARE @pos INT
>
> SET @Pos = PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',@Input)
>
> WHILE @Pos > 0
>
> BEGIN
>
> ```
> SET @Input = STUFF(@Input,@pos,1,'')
>
> SET @Pos = PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',@Input)
> ```
>
> END
>
> SELECT  @Input

**Thank You,
Vishal Patel**

Answer (score 1):

I have this function to pull numerics (0-9) from a string:

```
CREATE FUNCTION NumbersOnly(@STR VARCHAR(2000))
RETURNS VARCHAR(1000)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @N INT
    DECLARE @NN VARCHAR(1000)
    SET @N = 0
    SET @NN = ''

    WHILE @N <= LEN(@STR)
    BEGIN
        IF SUBSTRING(@STR,@N,1) >= '0'
            AND SUBSTRING(@STR,@N,1) <= '9'
        BEGIN
            SET @NN = @NN + SUBSTRING(@STR,@N,1)
        END
        SET @N = @N + 1
    END

RETURN @NN
END
```

Comment: Thank you, however i got syntax error in the first line: `Expected something between '(' and '@'`

Comment: I tried this using SQL Server ... maybe there's a syntax difference?