# How to handle datatypes in Teradata?

Tags: teradata

I have the following test table, myTable

```
    id      name    phone
1   1.00    mike    46/6546468465
2   2.00    sdfg    4*-645
3   3.00    dfh     (475)40956043
4   4.00    dfgjhd  akpf(4095gj43
5   5.00    ryjhdrt )frf49094
6   6.00    hyrt    3
7   7.00    hrt     456
8   8.00    h       456456456
9   9.00    rth     54
```

I tried to select all numeric values of phone

```
SELECT OTRANSLATE(phone, OTRANSLATE(phone, '0123456789', ''), '') FROM 
FROM myTable
```

This gave me the following error: `Datatype 'phone' does not match a defined datatype name`

Comment: What version of Teradata are you using? What is the data type of the column `phone`?  Show the complete definition from the CREATE TABLE statement.  If the CHARACTER SET is not specified, what is the default on your system?

Comment: Version 14.01 I imported data using SAS : `phone` and `name` is varchar(25).

Comment: I'm cannot find any documentation on this `OTRANSLATE` function, but since you are using SAS, perhaps it would be easier to clean the data before loading it into Teradata.  If you want to do that, please create a new question and I can help; it's easy to do this in SAS. If I answered here it would be off-topic.  I use SAS and Teradata daily.

Comment: Well the `otranslate` is from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19405014/how-to-replace-all-nonnumeric-values     Also  i am just using sas to import TEST data because it is easier. In reality I am using whatever data is already in the database

Comment: Oh I see; then I suggest that you go back to that original question and ask for clarification.  The person who answered it is an extremely well-known Teradata developer.  I suggest you delete this question and wait for him to respond to your comment.  I'm sure he will, but he may be gone for today (it's rather late here).  I would trust almost anything Dieter says and I'm sure he will help you.

Comment: Thanks, Bob :-) oTranslate is one of the Oracle compatible functions which are built-in since TD14, previously they were available as C-UDFs. The name was be changed because there's already another function named TRANSLATE.